Check if a registry key exists and change a key based on whether it does or not
The company I work for has people using a VMWare setup for remote working, we have an issue with teams that when they're at home they can't use various features without changing a reg key, I've managed to find a registry key that only exists when they're logged in via VMWare so I'm trying to setup a script that detects if that key exists, if it does, change the relevant key to 1 and if it doesn't exist change the relevant key to 0.
$remoteloginkey = Test-Path "HKCU:\Volatile Environment\1\View_Client_BrokerName"

if ($remoteloginkey) {
    Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\Software\Policies\VMWare, Inc\VMWare WebRTCRedir" -Name "teamsEnabled" -Value 1
} else {
    Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\Software\Policies\VMWare, Inc\VMWare WebRTCRedir" -Name "teamsEnabled" -Value 0
}

I've managed to put this together that as far as I'm aware should work? However, I'm still learning powershell so it doesn't seem to work and not sure where I've gone wrong. It just says the "teamsEnabled" key doesn't exist but when I look in my regedit at the relevant place it seems to be there fine

Should you ALSO test if "HKLM:\Software\Policies\VMWare, Inc\VMWare WebRTCRedir" exists? it might be a simple case of difficult-to-detect mispelling in the name

What is the error code you get?

This question gets asked frequently.  If a path to a key does not exist, you need to create the path with new item.  The following article from Microsoft devblogs shows the code to do this.
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell-community/how-to-update-or-add-a-registry-key-value-with-powershell/
You may need to modify this code to include your logic to set the value to 1 if it is zero or to zero if it is 1.

Would I still need to create the path even if I can go into the registry location myself and see the key there? As in I go to HKLM:\Software\Policies\VMWare, Inc\VMWare WebRTCRedir and I can see teamsEnabled is there

The code has an if statement in there.  The condition is that powershell cannot "see" the key in the registry.  If poweshell cannot see the key, the code creates it.  Your code will need a second if statement, one that sets the value to 1 if it is 0 and to 0 if it is one.
